# Node.js ES6 class private storage

Tags: mysql, node.js, ecmascript-6, es6-class

I'm using ES6 to build by Node.js app class. I want to create a db class, so I did the following :

```
"use strict"

var ini = require('node-ini');
var mysql = require('mysql');
let _db = new WeakMap();

// Class de base pour la base de donnée 
class Db{
    constructor () {
        ini.parse('../config/settings.ini', function(err,data){
            if(err) {
                console.log(err);
                return;
            } else {
                _db.set(this, mysql.createConnection({
                    host     : data.database_MYSQL.host,
                    user     : data.database_MYSQL.username,
                    password : data.database_MYSQL.password,
                    database : data.database_MYSQL.schema
                }));
            }
        });
    }
}

module.exports = Db;
```

It's the first I'm trying to store a private variable, and I looked on the web for solutions. I found the Weakmap solution that I tried to implement. But the MySQL connection won't store it with the following source code. I have this output :

```
_db.set(this, mysql.createConnection({
                    ^
TypeError: Invalid value used as weak map key
    at WeakMap.set (native)
    at D:\supervision\application\class\db.js:15:21
    at D:\supervision\application\node_modules\node-ini\node-ini.js:168:12
    at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (fs.js:380:3)
```

So how to deal with it ?

EDIT :

Here is how caller know when it's initialised :

```
var db;

function instantiateDb(callback){
        db = new db_connector();
        callback(db);
}

instantiateDb(function(db){
    db.connectDatabase();
})
```

Comment: `this` is `undefined` inside the callback. Please see [How to access the correct `this` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback) for a solution. However, the overall approach seems questionable. Assuming that `parse` is asynchronous, how will the caller know when the initialization is complete?

Comment: The caller know it I tried to implement promise without success, so i use callback function, like in the edit

Comment: And at the moment the callback is called, `ini.parse` is *not* done yet. You are basically passing an incomplete object to the callback.

Answer (score 0):

`this` is `undefined` inside the callback, it is *not* referring to an instance of `Db`, hence you get that error. Have a look at [How to access the correct `this` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback) for how to solve that.

However, there is a much bigger problem here: You are performing an asynchronous operation inside the the constructor. That means whatever wants to use an instance of `Db` has no way of knowing when it will be fully initialized.

A better way of solving this is to have a static asynchronous method that returns a new, fully initialized instance of `Db`:

```
class Db {
  static get() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      ini.parse('../config/settings.ini', function(err,data){
        if (err) {
          reject(err);
        } else {
          resolve(new Db(data));
        }
      });
    });
  }

  constructor (data) {
    _db.set(this, mysql.createConnection({
      host     : data.database_MYSQL.host,
      user     : data.database_MYSQL.username,
      password : data.database_MYSQL.password,
      database : data.database_MYSQL.schema
    }));
  }
}
```

Which can then be used as

```
Db.get().then(db => {
  db.connectDatabase();
});
```